# Increase the Limit of Magento Cross-sell products

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, xml

I am using the latest magento version which is 1.9.0.1.

I have followed the following instructions to increase the limit of cross-sell products but something seems to be wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated. You can find the original post over here as well
[How to Increase the Number of Crosssell Items in Cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/how-to-increase-the-number-of-crosssell-items-in-cart)

But my code is written below here:

`Crosssell.php` in the directory `app/code/local/TestingMod/Checkout/Block/Cart`:

```
class TestingMod_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

//     /**
//      * Items quantity will be capped to this value
//      *
//      * @var int
//      */
//     protected $_maxItemCount = 100;

//     /**
//      * Get crosssell items
//      *
//      * @return array
//      */

public function getItemCount()
{
         return count($this->getItems());
}

public function getItems()
{
    $items = $this->getData(\'items\');
    if (is_null($items)) {
        $items = array();
        $ninProductIds = $this->_getCartProductIds();
        if ($ninProductIds) {
            $lastAdded = (int) $this->_getLastAddedProductId();
            if ($lastAdded) {
                $collection = $this->_getCollection()
                    ->addProductFilter($lastAdded);
                if (!empty($ninProductIds)) {
                    $collection->addExcludeProductFilter($ninProductIds);
                }
                $collection->setPositionOrder()->load();

                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                    $ninProductIds[] = $item->getId();
                    $items[] = $item;
                }
            }

            if (count($items) < 100) {
                $filterProductIds = array_merge($this->_getCartProductIds(), $this->_getCartProductIdsRel());
                $collection = $this->_getCollection()
                    ->addProductFilter($filterProductIds)
                    ->addExcludeProductFilter($ninProductIds)
                    ->setPageSize(100-count($items))
                    ->setGroupBy()
                    ->setPositionOrder()
                    ->load();
                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                    $items[] = $item;
                }
            }

        }

        $this->setData(\'items\', $items);
    }
    return $items;
}
}
```

`app/code/local/TestingMod/Checkout/etc` in `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <TestingMod_Checkout>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </TestingMod_Checkout>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart_crosssell>
                        TestingMod_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell
                    </cart_crosssell>
                </rewrite>
        </checkout>
        <testingmod_checkout>
            <class>TestingMod_Checkout_Block</class>
        </testingmod_checkout>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

`app/etc/modules` in `TestingMod_Checkout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <TestingMod_Checkout>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </TestingMod_Checkout>
</modules>
```

`app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/` in `checkout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="testingmod_checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 2):

Number of cross-sell products is capped to 4 and since core team did not provide us with method to change the $_maxItemCount we will implement our own :)

```
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Items quantity will be capped to this value
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_maxItemCount = 4;
```

So we create a Crosssell.php block and extend from Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell. Our block will be created in `app/code/local/TestingMod/Checkout/Block/Cart/`. You could, of course, implement another way to fetch the limit $value (Mage::getStoreConfig() for example) but I wanted to keep it simple.

```
class TestingMod_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell
{
    public function setMaxItems($value = 4)
    {
        $this->_maxItemCount = $value;
    }
}
```

We can now replace the default cross-sell block with our own and call setMaxItems() method via our layout update file. So create `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/testingmod/checkout.xml`

NOTE: You will probably want to create a layout update file in `your_package/your_theme` instead of `base/default`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="checkout.cart">
                <block type="testingmod_checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml">
                    <action method="setMaxItems"><value>10</value></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

Our module configuration file `app\code\local\TestingMod\Checkout\etc\config.xml` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TestingMod_Checkout>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </TestingMod_Checkout>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <testingmod_checkout>
                <class>TestingMod_Checkout_Block</class>
            </testingmod_checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <testingmod_checkout>
                    <file>testingmod/checkout.xml</file>
                </testingmod_checkout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And finally we register our module `app/etc/modules/TestingMod_Checkout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TestingMod_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout/>
            </depends>
        </TestingMod_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And that's it! Nice and simple, also no class rewrites.
Hope it helps.