# Crosssell rows dropped despite valid CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, cross-sells

Deleting all products for fresh start, then importing a CSV with six cross-sell items per SKU produces dropped cross-sell rows.

No errors reported at import stage:

```
Checked rows: 4157, checked entities: 706, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0

File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button
```

Re-exporting the data confirms that cross-sell rows are indeed lost - but total row count has increased to 4073, somehow.

Deleting all products then re-importing original CSV gives exact same results.

Store already successfully configured to cope with up to ten cross-sell items, as per 
[How to Increase the Number of Crosssell Items in Cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/how-to-increase-the-number-of-crosssell-items-in-cart)

Suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are importing the products via CSV, related, crosssells and upsells need to be present in the system before their reference. It is more than likely the cause of your problem. Try with importing catalog first and then import the relations. Create a second CSV file containing sku and crosssell columns and import that after the initial import is completed.

Comment: Thanks Prateek - you're right! That's exactly what was wrong.