# Simple way to to Increase the Number of Cross-sell Items in cart from 4 to 12?

Tags: cross-sells

I can't believe that Magento just decides for everyone that they should ONLY have 4 cross-sell items and that's it! I have 12 and I want all 12 of them to appear hopefully without the need to re-write half of the Magento code!

I found this:

[How to Increase the Number of Crosssell Items in Cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17594/how-to-increase-the-number-of-crosssell-items-in-cart)

but the article seems to be written for an older version of Magento. I have Magento 1.9.1

**Is there really no simple way to do this?**

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy this file in local folder with same directory structure:

`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

To

`app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Crosssell.php`

And change the max limit `$_maxItemCount` of cross sell as you want

```
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Items quantity will be capped to this value
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_maxItemCount = 4;
```